# how to deal with encrypted sqlite database in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have an encrypted version of an sqlite database
and also I have the `KEY`
but honestly I have no idea about using it or how to get the data from the encrypted database?

I guess the solution somewhere in the open function?

```
 if(sqlite3_open([_dbPath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK);
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: You have to know what encryption scheme is being used.  After you retrieve a string from the DB, you'll have to decrypt it using whatever scheme was used to decrypt it.

Comment: What do you mean saying encrypted version of sqlite database ?

Comment: @bdares ...I know everything about encryption cuz i have the code in c#..but I mean is there anyway like .net,u put the key inside the connection string??

Comment: I seriously doubt it.  DBs are for storing data, not encrypting them.  You'll need to use a cipher to decrypt the strings.  Use the same cipher with the same key and you'll be fine.

Comment: thats fine if I can see the data...the main problem it won't even open the connection!! I found a commercial extension"cerdo" !! but there should a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core SQLite database implementation does not itself provide encryption support. There does however exist a number of extensions for adding encryption to SQLite. Some of these encrypt the entire database file while some other only encrypt the contents of the tables.

These extensions are for the most part not compatible, so you will most likely have to use the same extension on the iPhone as the one used on C#. And if you're lucky that extension is also supported on iOS.

Comment: I guess am not lucky in that...I'll try to use the SQLchipher and openssl...if u know any thing about them pls tell me..
and thnx a lot