# Iphone database data encryption

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I opened an sqlite database file, and it seems to have many rows that arent readable. The data has got weird symbols including "question mark diamonds". Is it data that iphone encrypts when it goes to the database and decrypts back. Is there a way to read the data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820226/how-to-deal-with-encrypted-sqlite-database-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible. You need encyription algorithm (aes,3des or others), public and private key.